# Sql Server Issue During Update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Hello I am little bit confused to see the sql server behaviour on executing the query. According to mine the output should be "Priyanka" ,4

```
Declare @temp table(
Name Varchar(50),
amount int
)

insert @temp values ('Priyanka' ,10 )

Update @temp
set amount=amount-A.a
from (
select  'Priyanka' as Name,1 as a 
union
select  'Priyanka' as Name,5 as a
)A
where [@temp].Name in (A.Name)

select * from @temp
```

But
the output

```
Name    amount
Priyanka    9
```

Can any one Please tell me why this is happened.

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL doesn't support a `from` clause with `update` and you'd instead have to write your access to other tables as a direct subquery in the `set` clause. If you did that, you'd get the error "subquery returned more than one value" and have some idea of the issue.

Unfortunately, the Microsoft extension to SQL that allows a `FROM` clause also *silently* ignores the fact that multiple rows may match, uses one of those rows and ignores the others.<sup>1</sup>

If you're going to use this extension, it's up to you to carefully ensure that you don't have multiple matches to a single row in the target table.

I'd rearrange your query, something like:

```
Declare @temp table(
Name Varchar(50),
amount int
)

insert @temp values ('Priyanka' ,10 )

;With A as
(
select  'Priyanka' as Name,1 as a 
union
select  'Priyanka' as Name,5 as a
)
Update t
set amount=amount-Aa.a
from
    @temp t
        cross apply
    (select SUM(a) as a from A where Name = t.Name) Aa

select * from @temp
```

Where I use the `cross apply` to aggregate the data down to a single row per target row.

---

<sup>1</sup>Importantly, though, it does support the concept that the effects of an `UPDATE` are applied "as if" all rows (and columns within them) are updated in parallel. So you *don't* get that first the update applies using one row and then the second update gets to update an already updated row.

Comment: But sir when we read from xml and update the table then no issue .

Comment: I am little bit confused. Can u please give me a reference from where i can understand this concept.

Answer (score 0):

You need to SUM the values of the union entries. Simply UNION the entries it have multiple entries so it may take any one entry and ignore the remains.

For your case the following query will work:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (NAME VARCHAR(50), amount INT)

INSERT @temp
VALUES ('Priyanka', 10)

UPDATE t
SET amount = t.amount - A.a
FROM @temp t
JOIN (
    SELECT NAME, SUM(a) AS a FROM (
        SELECT 'Priyanka' AS NAME, 1 AS a
        UNION
        SELECT 'Priyanka' AS NAME, 5 AS a
        ) c
    GROUP BY NAME
    ) A ON A.NAME = t.NAME

SELECT * FROM @temp
```

Comment: But sir,  When We read from XML instead of select then it working fine for me.